# Collate strings into tree from stored procedure output

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a complex stored procedure `MyStoredProc` (which I can't change, it's greatly simplified for the example) that takes an Id and returns a list of Ids and Titles, alike so:

Input = 100

```
Id     Title      HasChilds
----------------------------
101    CategoryA  0
102    CategoryB  0
103    CategoryC  1
104    CategoryD  0
```

Input = 103

```
Id     Title      HasChilds
----------------------------
105    SubCatA    0
106    SubCatB    1
107    SubCatC    0
```

Input = 106

```
Id     Title      HasChilds
----------------------------
108    SubA       0
109    SubB       0
```

My goal is to write a query to collate this into a single line, with branches put in parenthesis:

```
CategoryA, CategoryB, CategoryC (SubCatA, SubCatB (SubA, SubB), SubCatC), CategoryD
```

Given that there are no more than 4-5 levels deep, how can I do that in T-SQL?

I have tried dumping `MyStoredProc` output to a temp table

```
INSERT INTO #tmpTable 
  EXEC MyStoredProc @_Id = 100
```

then walking through it with a cursor and appending branches to the same temp table. And that's where I'm stuck. I don't know how can I append `ParentId` to a temp tables rows, so that I could walk with a cursor from last line to first appending branches strings to a parent line string. Maybe that's a wrong approach altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it (note half of the script here is to set up data that matches your example):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyStoredProc (
    @Id INT)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @Id = 100
    BEGIN
        SELECT 101 AS Id, 'CategoryA' AS Title, 0 AS HasChilds
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 102 AS Id, 'CategoryB' AS Title, 0 AS HasChilds
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 103 AS Id, 'CategoryC' AS Title, 1 AS HasChilds
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 104 AS Id, 'CategoryD' AS Title, 0 AS HasChilds
    END;
    IF @Id = 103
    BEGIN
        SELECT 105 AS Id, 'SubCatA' AS Title, 0 AS HasChilds
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 106 AS Id, 'SubCatB' AS Title, 1 AS HasChilds
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 107 AS Id, 'SubCatC' AS Title, 0 AS HasChilds
    END;
    IF @Id = 106
    BEGIN
        SELECT 108 AS Id, 'SubA' AS Title, 0 AS HasChilds
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 109 AS Id, 'SubB' AS Title, 0 AS HasChilds
    END;
END;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE GetCategoryList(
    @StartId INT,
    @Result VARCHAR(2048) OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tmpTable TABLE (
        Id INT,
        Title VARCHAR(50),
        HasChilds INT);
    INSERT INTO @tmpTable EXEC MyStoredProc @StartId;
    DECLARE @Id INT = NULL;
    SELECT TOP 1 @Id = Id FROM @tmpTable ORDER BY Id;
    SELECT @Result = '';
    WHILE @Id IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Title VARCHAR(50);
        DECLARE @HasChilds INT;
        SELECT @Title = Title, @HasChilds = HasChilds FROM @tmpTable WHERE Id = @Id;
        SELECT @Result = @Result + @Title;
        IF @HasChilds = 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT @Result = @Result + ', ';
        END;
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @Append VARCHAR(2048);
            EXEC GetCategoryList @Id, @Append OUTPUT;
            SELECT @Result = @Result + ' (' + @Append + '), ';
        END;

        --Get the next id
        DECLARE @LastId INT;
        SELECT @LastId = @Id;
        SELECT @Id = NULL;
        SELECT TOP 1 @Id = Id FROM @tmpTable WHERE Id > @LastId ORDER BY Id;
    END;
    SELECT @Result = SUBSTRING(@Result, 1, LEN(@Result) - 1);
END;
GO
DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(2048);
EXEC GetCategoryList 100, @Result OUTPUT;
SELECT @Result;
```